# Sonata Media Bundle gallery dont show image

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

i will try to add image gallery to my product entity. In my database all looks ok, in product table he had a gallery id, in admin panel i can set gallery to product. In twig when i try to show my product image this way:

```
    <div>
        {% for image in product.gallery %}
            {% media image,'small' %}

        {% else %}
            No image
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I have No image message, when doing by this way:

```
     <div>
        {% for image in product.gallery.galleryHasMedias %}
            {% media image,'small' %}

        {% else %}
            No image
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Have no message and empty div witohut image. {{ dump(product) }} return me this:
[image]

So in gallery field i have 4 images (its exacly what i add). How to show them on twig?